# Force "Content-Type: text/plain" to display in browser page

Tags: php, character-encoding, plaintext

I used to set:

> header("Content-Type: text/plain");

when i wanted to display all chars of a PHP output, but now it seems that if there are special chars in this output (\x00 \x01 and so on), the browser tries to download the page instead of displaying it.

I tried to set the charset this way:

> header('Content-Type:text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1');

but the result is the same.

Even though this one works (browser displays as page instead of trying to download):

> header('Content-Type:text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15');

it's not really good since some chars are not really shown (like \x88 or \x91 and others).

So is there any way i can output a text/plain containing special chars and using ISO-8859-1 charset and force the browser to display this output in the page instead of trying to download it?

Comment: If it's really iso-8859-1 it should not contain invalid characters, so perhaps you should clean it up first.

Comment: \x00 and \x01 are none printable characters, what would be the purpose of trying to show them in a browser? Are you filtering your output properly?

Comment: @One Trick Pony: using UTF-8 i get a bunch of �

Comment: @Jack: i need to display them i dont want to remove them

Comment: @Kristoffer S Hansen: \x00 and \x01 were just examples. \x88 is a displayable char but it gives the same forced-download issue

Comment: @Fabius Do you know which character set your original data set is in? ISO-8859-1, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-8 etc?

Comment: @KristofferSHansen since i'm just trying display a SHA1 as chars instead of hex representation, there's not really a charset for original data. but ISO-8859-1 is the only one that could display it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an odd experiment, and you should probably send text/html instead, possibly with `pre` markup.

Anyway, octets 88 and 91 (hex.) denote control characters in ISO-8859-1, with no generally accepted assignment. If they are supposed to be printable characters, you should probably declare windows-1252 instead.

Comment: Windows-1252 seems to work pretty fine, even if i'm not really sure about all it's chars rapresentation so i will check them from \x00 to \xFF and see if they all match ISO-8859-1. i'm still wondering why ISO-8859-1 started giving download issue during last months but worked fine in the past...